# C# Attribute that overrides empty properties

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to add custom attribute on Class, that override all empty string properties? Something like this:

```
[DefaultValueForEmptyString(Text="N/A")]
public class PersonsDTO 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultValueForEmptyString
{
   public static void MapProperties(object Properties, string text) 
   {
       foreach (var property in Properties)
       {
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
          {
             property = text // "N/A in this case
          }     
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to *define* such an attribute, but to *interpret* it. As there´s no such thing existing, you´d have to write your own logic for what to do with a property if it has the attribute.

Comment: Attributes are **passive** (in general). They don't get to run any code at runtime unless/until something explicitly makes them do so.

Comment: Attributes typically don't alter the behaviour of classes, they add meta data.

Comment: How many string fields are typically in your class?  At the moment, you are creating a lot of work (creating meta-data and initialisation code) to save 3 lines of `= "N/A";`; at the end of each property line.

Comment: I also would want to add, that this "solution" is working on the wrong end of the problem. The UI should replace `string.Empty` with your desired "EmptyDisplayString" ...

Comment: @Neil `= "N/A"` won't override when property has value `""` so basically is empty but has been initialized by that empty value.

Comment: Is this in WPF? In that case a Behavior may be preferable. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgartner/2009/11/11/wpf-attached-behavior-example-watermark-text/

Answer (score 5):

To resolve a similar problem ages ago I implemented an extension to handle this :

```
public static string ValueOrDefault(this string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? "N/A" : value;
}
```

Now you can use this on all your string properties :

```
var person = new PersonsDTO();
//Prints N/A
Console.WriteLine(person.Name.ValueOrDefault());
```

That's not really impressive but the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to make a custom string class that implicitly converts from your custom class to string and from a string to your custom class. It's a bit heavy handed, but so is making a custom attribute class.

I made a .NET fiddle showing an example of this [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2wgk52)

A copy of the code is below in case .NET fiddle goes away.

```
using System;

public class DefaultString
{
    private const string _default = "N/A";
    
    public DefaultString(string normal)
    {
        Value = normal;
    }
    
    private string _value = _default;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                _value = _default;
            else
                _value = value;
        }
    }
    
    public bool IsDefault()
    {
        return Value == _default;
            
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
    
    public static implicit operator string(DefaultString defaultString)
    {
        if (defaultString == null)
            return _default;
        
        return defaultString.ToString();
    }
    
    public static implicit operator DefaultString(string normal)
    {
        return new DefaultString(normal);
    }
}

public class Program
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        DefaultString nullDefault = null;
        DefaultString nullConstructorDefault = new DefaultString(null);
        DefaultString emptyDefault = String.Empty;
        DefaultString emptyConstructorDefault = new DefaultString(String.Empty);
        DefaultString abcDefault = "abc";
        DefaultString abcConstructorDefault = new DefaultString("abcConstructor");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Default string assigned to null: " + nullDefault);
        Console.WriteLine("Default string constructed with null: " + nullConstructorDefault);
        Console.WriteLine("Default string assigned empty string: " + emptyDefault);
        Console.WriteLine("Default string constructed with empty string: " + emptyConstructorDefault);
        Console.WriteLine("Default string assigned \"abc\": " + abcDefault);
        Console.WriteLine("Default string constructed with \"abcConstructor\": " + abcConstructorDefault);
    }
}
```

The output should be:

> Default string assigned to null: N/A
>
> Default string constructed with null: N/A
>
> Default string assigned empty string: N/A
>
> Default string constructed with empty string: N/A
>
> Default string assigned "abc": abc
>
> Default string constructed with "abcConstructor": abcConstructor